# Convertir String a Date en Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, model, thymeleaf

Recibo con el modelo la fecha en String y me gustaría convertirla para seguir teniendo en el formulario input type text para seguir teniendo la opción del Date, ya se hacerlo con el input type text pero me gustaría usar el type date.

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date" class="form-control-label">Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{date}" id="date"/>
        <div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('date')}" th:errors="*{date}"></div>
    </div>
```

como lo tengo al recibir el dato en string no me carga.
Alguna idea para dar formato al

```
th:field="*{date}"
```

me gustaría funcionnar con

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" th:field="*{date}" id="date"/>
```

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo: ¿quieres tener el modelo en formato date y estás preguntando sobre como formatearlo y parsearlo para trabajar con él?

Comment: el tema es que la vista me carga el modelo y con el modelo date me viene en String y  a mi me gustaría cargarlo en tipo date para tener lo de la fecha del input type date

Comment: La **vista** debe mostrar un texto que el usuario pueda leer, es el modelo el que debería ser Date.

Comment: si, correcto la fecha en el modelo la tenía en String a ver si así me funciona, gracias